# IIS redirect preserve QueryString?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

I have a url:

http://mywebsite.com/Account/?Number=25191108&Name=Something&Remote=False

which I would like to redirect to:

http://anotherwebsite.com/whatever/

and preserve the query string:

http://anotherwebsite.com/whatever/?Number=25191108&Name=Something&Remote=False

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Found this link: http://oneidia.blogspot.com/2010/09/simple-http-redirect-with-querystring.html

Comment: https://msftplayground.com/2011/01/http-redirect-with-query-string-in-iis-7/

Answer (score 116, accepted):

1. Go into the IIS site properties for the domain you're moving from. In the "Home Directory" tab, click the option "A redirection to a URL"
2. In the Redirect to box, enter the domain you wish to move to (no trailing slash), plus $S$Q - for example, http://www.YourDomain.com$S$Q
3. Next, check the options that state the client will be sent to "The exact URL entered above", and "A permanent redirection for this resource"

Comment: I found this which helped me: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4678/permanent-301-redirect-with-querystring-in-iis/ so when I saw this SO question, I figured I'd upvote it here too in case I have to find it again in the future...

Comment: NOTE! $V$Q seems to be the new addition in IIS7+ (instead of $S$Q). S changed to V. Not sure why but anyway $V$Q works for me.

Comment: reference on the wildcard values for HTTP Redirects in IIS: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737576.aspx

Comment: This site does a good job of explaining how it works in IIS 7 https://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/client-side-redirection-using-httpredirection-module

Answer (score 18):

You can see the complete solution here:

[image]

Tried it in IIS 10 and works as expected.

The status code can be anything you prefer. 301 for permanent redirect and 302/307 for temporary redirect.

Comment: Broken image links are the SO version of "And I've discovered the murderer isAAARGH".