# httpRedirect in Web.Config With old URL as the querystring on the redirect

Tags: c#, iis, web-config, http-redirect

I have an httpRedirect for pdf files that works fine.  What I need is to add the original URL to the end of the redirection as a querystring

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
<add wildcard="*.pdf" destination="/test.aspx?pdf=<OLD_URL>"/>
</httpRedirect>
```

Comment: See the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147806/iis-redirect-preserve-querystring

Comment: That seems to work for query strings but i need the entire URL