# C# web application -> proxy all requests -> return content from another web application (Reverse proxy)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, proxy

I would like to proxy every requests to a web application, pass it to another web application and then return my other web applications response to the original sender.

It should be able to handle all `http methods` and `content-types` etc. I should also be able to edit the incoming request and add additional headers and content.

The background for doing this is the security architecture for a project that has one web server in a public DMZ and then another web server in the internal network that is allowed to talk to the database server.

[image]

Found a thread for ASP.NET core but preferably it should be done with .Net Framework and not be dependent on an external library.

[Creating a proxy to another web api with Asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000362/creating-a-proxy-to-another-web-api-with-asp-net-core)

Comment: what's your question? If you just want to pass on requests and responses verbatim you don't need another application, just a general gateway server, I'd have thought. Those kinds of tools can probably add the odd extra header etc if needed.

Comment: @ADyson I need to be able to add additional headers and content to the request, see paragraph two.

Comment: yes some gateway software I believe can do that. But again, what's your _question_? Also why do you need to pass on requests? Is this "client portal" an API or a GUI? It _sounds_ like a GUI. So user makes request to the GUI, GUI makes request to the API...sounds pretty standard?

Comment: @ADyson I'm sorry if the question is poorly asked. I found an answer myself but the reason for the pass of requests is because I need to add a certificate to each request. This can not be handled in the GUI because then the client would have access to this certificate.

Comment: "This can not be handled in the GUI because then the client would have access to this certificate." Not if the GUI's backend (i.e. server-side code) is making the request. Anyway, glad you found a solution.

Comment: @ADyson Poorly formulated then because this is exactly what I was after and what my solution is. For me GUI for web application is the client (browser) and API is back end. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a good answer for Web API that led me in the right direction.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41680404/3850405

I started out by adding a new ASP.NET Web Application -> MVC -> No Authentication.

I then removed everything accept `Global.asax`, `packages.config` and `Web.config`.

I then edited `Global.asax` to use a `DelegatingHandler` like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(CustomHttpProxy.Register);
    }
}

public static class CustomHttpProxy
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Proxy",
            routeTemplate: "{*path}",
            handler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
                innerHandler: new HttpClientHandler(),
                handlers: new DelegatingHandler[]
                {
                    new ProxyHandler()
                }
            ),
            defaults: new { path = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null
        );
    }
}

public class ProxyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var forwardUri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);
        forwardUri.Host = "localhost";
        forwardUri.Port = 62904;
        request.RequestUri = forwardUri.Uri;

        if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
        {
            request.Content = null;
        }

        request.Headers.Add("X-Forwarded-Host", request.Headers.Host);
        request.Headers.Host = "localhost:62904";
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        return response;
    }
}
```

After this I had to add the static content and then everything worked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer - very helpful! Though, I had to Nuget this package: **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost**